# How to ensure object values contain their key with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, template-literals, typescript-template-literals

Using TypeScript [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), I'm able to ensure that the object values are made of a `Color` and the string `-primary`.

```
type Color = "green" | "blue" | "orange" | "red" | "purple" | "pink";
type ColorObject<Key extends string = Color> = Record<Key, `${Key}-primary`>;

const COLORS: ColorObject = {
    green: "green-primary",
    blue: "blue-primary",
    orange: "orange-primary",
    red: "red-primary",
    purple: "purple-primary",
    pink: "pink-primary"
};
```

But I would like to ensure that the value is the same as the key, i.e:

```
pink: "pink-primary" // good
pink: "red-primary" // bad
```

I searched quite a lot, not sure it's possible as the time I write this... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to achieve it. In your current implementation, your type allows any string color to have any of the colors in the value. Instead by using mapped typed we will map through the colors separately and assign the corresponding value to them:

```
type Color = 'green' | 'blue' | 'orange' | 'red' | 'purple' | 'pink';
type ColorObject<Key extends string = Color> = {
  [K in Key]: `${K}-primary`;
};

const COLORS: ColorObject = {
  green: 'green-primary',
  blue: 'orange-primary', // expected error
  orange: 'orange-primary',
  red: 'red-primary',
  purple: 'purple-primary',
  pink: 'pink-primary',
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigcgObIhAO0ygB8sAjBAVwmLMxQEMDtbSs8ATOrMK5MAjb0wASwIBrTAG4AUKEixEKAPLkAVhADGwADwBpCCCgQAHsEKcAzlCvBk47OiVJkAPmcBvWVCgBtfShxKEMQAF0ALigAAwAST30AXwBaMAcAW0ZkEGi5RLlZLTgCO1gVABkVACUAZSj4VzVNHS8fKFx8AiicPEJUjKyQTAAaNsoabqYWCH7RTOyRqAB6JZNTSB0IThNkZBQ2qdZJ5GZWWfmh0d8ubq5zwZG2vgEhbufBGbS5h6uoMUk3uIJPcFqN8rIgA)

Comment: Bonus: how if I don't have a list of all my colors i.e.`Color`? Would there still be a way to validate `{ foo: "foo-primary" }`? Thanks

Comment: You can do that like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpxjam)

Comment: I struggled for so long to find this kind of answer, thanks!